# Microsoft.PointOfService.PosPrinter - Method printbitmap threw an Exception

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, hardware

I'm attempting to print a bitmap from an Espon receipt printer.  The full error is as follows:

> Method printbitmap threw an Exception. A class-specific error
>   condition  occurred. The error condition code is available in the
>   ResultCodeExtended  property.

I can't find this ResultCodeExtended property.  Any suggestions as to what might cause this error?  From what I know, this code has been in place for ages and nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the pixel format of the bitmap.  It was being read in at 24bppIndexed, it needed to be 8bppIndexed.

Comment: How did you find out that? I am struggling with printing an image.

Comment: I apologize, it's been many years since I worked on this issue and I do not recall how I came to this conclusion.  I very well could have been a requirement of the hardware, or that the image was originally 8bppIndexed.